# Using perl, how do we print lines between two patterns, skipping first match?

Tags: regex, perl

As a motivating example, say we have a document with titled sections, and we want to extract a section using its name and the name of the following section. We could do that with a perl one-liner like this one:

`perl -ne 'print if /^<SECTION-NAME-1>$$/ .. /^<SECTION-NAME-2>$$/'`

Now, say our document has a table of contents which lists the same sections, and we wish to ignore the first matches of both of these. How would one do this in perl?

Example input:

```
<SECTION-NAME-1>
we do not care what is here
<SECTION-NAME-2>
or here
<SECTION-NAME-1>
this is the magic stuff
that we would like to extract
<SECTION-NAME-2>
do not need this either
```

Desired out:

```
<SECTION-NAME-1>
this is the magic stuff
that we would like to extract
<SECTION-NAME-2>
```

Output of above one-liner, which mistakenly includes the top portion:

```
<SECTION-NAME-1>
we do not care what is here
<SECTION-NAME-2>
<SECTION-NAME-1>
this is the magic stuff
that we would like to extract
<SECTION-NAME-2>
```

Comment: are the section titles numbered or similarly identified as titles? otherwise it seems that a lot more cases than just the toc could match the pattern, e.g. for "Methods" and "Results" it seems plausible that those terms appear in more places in the text before the respective sections (maybe in the introduction "the rest of this paper is structured as follows [...]" etc)

Comment: Perhaps like this? `\A<SECTION-NAME-1>(?:\R(?!<SECTION-NAME-1>).*)*\R\K<SECTION-NAME-1>(?:\R(?!<SECTION-NAME-).*)*\R<SECTION-NAME-\d+>` https://regex101.com/r/o6w0Nh/1

Comment: @nonthevisor Yes, there are potentially other mentions, that's right! But...for the sake of upping my own regex skills, I thought I'd start with the simpler case. :D

Comment: Or a bit shorter `\A(<SECTION-NAME-)1>(?:\R(?!(?1)1>).*)*\R\K(?1)1>(?:\R(?!(?1)).*)*\R(?1)\d+>` https://regex101.com/r/atRoLO/1

Comment: @SeanEaster sorry, I missed the regex tag, and was thus thinking of iterations

Comment: @Thefourthbird the last digit match in your regex only makes sense with numbered section titles, which is probably not what OP wants. other than that, you should probably post your comment as an answer.

Comment: Depending on your use case, this might be enough: `perl -ne 'print if (/^<SECTION-NAME-1>$/ && $cnt++) .. /^<SECTION-NAME-2>$/'`

Answer (score 2):

We could keep using `..`.

```sh
perl -ne'
   next if !( my $ff = /^<SECTION-NAME-1>$/ .. /^<SECTION-NAME-2>$/ );
   print if $skipped;
   $skipped = 1 if $ff =~ /E/;
'
```

But that complicates things without advantage.

```sh
perl -ne'
   next if !( $in ||= /^<SECTION-NAME-1>$/ );
   print if $skipped;
   $skipped = 1, $in = 0 if /^<SECTION-NAME-2>$/;
'
```

Comment: Why the uncheck? Is there a problem with what I posted?